# stored procedure where condition not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure to select data from a table. but if I put where condition in it. Then it is throwing an error

> "Incorrect syntax near '='."

But if i remove where condition then this query will work fine. can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong in where condition.

```
alter procedure [dbo].[GetCompleteCPTDetails]
    @Practice_Short_Name varchar(50) = null,
    @Uploaded_Date varchar(max) = null
as
begin
DECLARE @CPTtablename varchar(100)
DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(max)
set @CPTtablename = 'ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_'+@Practice_Short_Name+''
SET @vQuery = 'select Practice_Short_Name,Service_Date_From,Carrier_Name,
   Location_Description,Patient_Number,Patient_First_Name,
   Patient_Last_Name,Voucher_Number,Procedure_Code,Service_Fees,
   Service_Payments,Service_Adjustments,Acer_Status,Acer_Allowed_Amount    
from ' + @CPTtablename + 'where Uploaded_Date ='+ @Uploaded_Date +'
order by acer_status asc, Service_Date_From desc, Patient_First_Name asc'

EXEC (@vQuery)

end
GO
```

Comment: try to `PRINT @vQuery` before `EXEC` and see what is the query being generated.

Comment: You should be using `N` before all literal strings when using `nvarchar`. i.e.`set @CPTtablename = N'ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_'...`. Although not sure it would fix the issue you're seeing, hence this is a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For date `@Uploaded_Date` you need quotas as below

```
alter procedure [dbo].[GetCompleteCPTDetails]
    @Practice_Short_Name varchar(50) = null,
    @Uploaded_Date varchar(max) = null
as
begin
DECLARE @CPTtablename varchar(100)
DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(max)
set @CPTtablename = 'ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_'+@Practice_Short_Name+''
SET @vQuery = 'select Practice_Short_Name,Service_Date_From,Carrier_Name,
   Location_Description,Patient_Number,Patient_First_Name,
   Patient_Last_Name,Voucher_Number,Procedure_Code,Service_Fees,
   Service_Payments,Service_Adjustments,Acer_Status,Acer_Allowed_Amount    
from ' + @CPTtablename + ' where Uploaded_Date ='''+ @Uploaded_Date +'''
order by acer_status asc, Service_Date_From desc, Patient_First_Name asc'

EXEC (@vQuery)

end
GO
```

Comment: @SaurabhMosesRam I added spec before `where` try it now please

Comment: I think you need to add space as well before `order by acer_status`

Comment: @rikitikitik it looks like `Uploaded_Date ='2014-01-01'order by` so I think It's good